# How to get html id output in src

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, video

Trying to get html id output in a video source src and poster

```
<video id="really-cool-video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls
 preload="auto" width="640" height="264" poster="$('#posterURL').html();"
 data-setup='{}'>
  <source src="$('#videoURL').html();" type='video/mp4'>
</video>

<div id="posterURL"></div>

<div id="videoURL"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)-function of jQuery for this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var posterUrl = $('#posterURL').html();
    var videoUrl = $('#videoURL').html();

    $('#really-cool-video').attr('poster', posterUrl);
    $('source').attr('src', videoUrl);
)};
```